# Backup Photoshop custom shapes etc

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I'm about to install Windows 8 clean and I'd like to backup all the Photoshop preferences like custom shapes, patterns etc.

Can someone help me out? Google didn't help me.

I'm using Adobe Photoshop CS5 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/375776) information in the Adobe Photoshop Windows FAQ, they're stored in a `*.psp` file somewhere on your hard disk. This means you could just make a copy of that file to back it up.

To verify this, you could try an experiment of deleting the file after making a copy (or just moving it), running Photoshop to see if they're gone, and then restoring the file and running it again to see if they've be restored.